# java - Create a Comparator for a type that contains type parameters

Tags: java, generics, comparator, type-parameter

I have a class defined as `MyClass<T, S>` for which I'd like to create a Comparator for MyClass where T and S extend Foo.

How can I go about doing this?

Unsuccessful attempts:

```
// Warning: The type parameter MyClass is hiding the type MyClass<T,S>
public class MyComparator<MyClass> implements Comparator<MyClass>

// Syntax errors and the warning from above
public class MyComparator<MyClass<T, S>> implements Comparator<MyClass<T, S>>

// Syntax errors
public class MyComparator<MyClass<T extends Foo, S extends Foo>> implements Comparator<MyClass<T extends Foo, S extends Foo>>

// Syntax errors and the warning from above
public class MyComparator<MyClass<? extends Foo, ? extends Foo>> implements Comparator<MyClass<? extends Foo, ? extends Foo>>
```

And various combinations of the above. What is the correct way? Thank you.

Comment: Why are those attempts unsuccessful? Do you get error messages or do they not work as intended? Please don't forget to include such stuff when asking for *"Why does my code not work, help"*.

Comment: Why is your `Comparator` implementing `Comparable`?!

Comment: ... it should implement `Comparator<...>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is not generic. It always compares the same type of objects, ans this type is `MyClass<? extends Foo, ? extends Foo>`.

So it should be

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<MyClass<? extends Foo, ? extends Foo>>
```